# How do I do this mongodb query? Searching through children of collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm newish to MongoDB (and mongoDB queries) and so I have a question of how I would write a query doing the following...

With a Schema like the one I'm illustrating below... how would I return a collection of all post comments by only a particular user? I would need this for something like generating a list of a users comments for their own profile page, for instance. It is my intention, however, to leave comments as children of posts as opposed to childrens of a user. I assume that I do not need to keep redundant comment records and that this query is possible somehow (probably simple but I'm a newb).

```
{ title: "someTitle",
  author: "someAuthor",
  created: Date,
  comments: [{authorId: objectId, content: "commentContent"},{authorId: objectId, content: "commentContent"}],
  postContent: "This is the content of the post"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to list the comments whose authorId is same or whose author is same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such case much better to make comments separate collection:

```
comments
{
  authorid,
  postId,
  content
}
```

Then you could easy query user comments:

```
db.comments.find({authorid: 5});
```

Your schema is not working for your business or will some kind of pain for you.

Answer (score 1):

This schema this schema is not the best solution, I would go with separate collection for comments or store comments twice. But with Mongo DB 2.2 you could do it with following aggregation query:

```
db.articles.aggregate(
    {$unwind : '$comments'}, 
    {$match : {'comments.authodId' : 'authodId'}},
    {$project : {comments : 1}});
```

Please also check [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) .